# annoted Bean not getting injected with EJB and JSF

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x

I am nea to EJB3 and JSF. I am facing issue with bean injection and getting NullPointerException.

I have twi different modules - EJB & WEB
EJB Module has below class:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class TestFacadeBean implements TestFacade {

.........
....
}

@Local
public interface TestFacade {

........

}
```

I am using this bean in my WEB module as below:

```
public class UserBean {

@EJB
private TestFacade  testFacade;


public void useBean(){
      testFacade.use();//this throws NullPointerException
}

}
```

UserBean is configured in faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
        <description>User Bean</description>
        <managed-bean-name>userBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.test.managed.UserBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

I tries to check value for bean testFacade and found it is null. Bean is not getting set.

Comment: At what point are you calling `useBean`?

Comment: I get exception on calling testFacade.use(); I am calling useBean() to authenticate user. it is after application is deployed and when user tries to login.

Comment: So it's being called on the click of a button, as an `action`?